# Can I add Media Web Part to Application Page?

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, application-pages, media-streaming

I am trying to implement a video library page in Sharepoint.  What I have is a Video Library where each of subfolder will represent a playlist.  I want to create an Application Page which will have a default video inside of a Media Web Part and a list of playlists.  The user can either watch the video or click on one of the playlists to see the contents of the playlist.  This will post back to the same page with updated query string to indicate which playlist.  The content of the playlist will just be displayed on the same page as a list of videos instead of a list of playlist.  The Media Web Part will also be updated with a default video for that playlist.  When a user clicks one of the videos in the list, that video will be set as the Media Web Part's video in the code behind.  This is how the client wants it.

Basically:

How can I add a Media Web Part to an Application Page in Visual Studio? ..and..
How can I update it's video content in the code behind?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a server control, so i don't see why you couldn't do what you want with it in an application page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.mediawebpart.aspx